# Internal Server Error updating Watson's STT Language Model

Tags: speech-to-text, ibm-watson

A few days ago we started seeing Internal Server Errors in responses to Watson's custom language model training requests. Here's the error message:

> "error": "{\"code\":500,\"code_description\":\"Internal Server
>   Error\",\"error\":\"sreq 95f48de6 aborted  PUT
>   ServiceUrl(customizationsStore,customizations/682ed9c9-fbab-48dc-8c6c-44b46c23e2db/patch.en-US_BroadbandModel.v2017-11-15)
>   {} after timeout of 100.000000s.\"}",

This custom model is no longer usable as a result. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check your model now. I am guessing you were experiencing an intermittent error. Sending another `train` request usually helps.